# Matlab-Select particular values in a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am a beginner in matlab and I have a particular z matrix of size m×1 with values 0,1,3,5,2 etc..with above values repeating. Now I have 4 other column matrix `x1`,`x2`,`x3` and `y` and I want to do regression.

I have used `lm = LinearModel.fit(x,y,'linear')` specifying columns.Now I want to do regression only for values in matrix `x1`,`x2`,`x3` and `y` for those corresponding to z matrix with value of 1 and neglect the other rows.How do I do it?

Comment: Could you provide simple, repeatable example code that would help others understand the problem and goal?

Comment: Unrelated hint: Use `Alt-0215` for the multiplication character × instead of x in postings. It really looks much better as m×1 instead if mx1.

Answer (score 1):

That's very simple.  I'm going to assume that your matrix of predictor variables and outputs are also of size `m` (number of samples).  All you have to do is find the locations within `z` that are 1, subset your 3 column matrix of `x1,x2,x3` and `y`, then use `LinearModel.fit` to fit your data.  Assuming your matrix of predictors is stored in `X`, and your outputs are stored in `y`, you would do this:

```
ind = z == 1;
xOut = X(ind,:);
yOut = y(ind);
lm1 = LinearModel.fit(xOut, yOut, 'linear');
```

BTW, these are very simple subsetting operations in MATLAB.  Suggest you read a tutorial before asking any further questions here.